# Issue with layoutTitle tag when upgrading to Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I'm getting the following exception when using the g:layoutTitle tag after upgrading my app to 2.4.4

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.Content2HTMLPage@21b3cfb7' with class 'com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.Content2HTMLPage' to class 'com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.AbstractHTMLPage'
```

I've tried with even just hardcoding a string as the default value, like this:

```
<title><g:layoutTitle default="Test"/></title>
```

And I still get the issue. Did I miss something when upgrading? I'm not sure what the issue is here.

I also get the same issue when using pageProperty. Ex:

```
<body class="${pageProperty(name: 'body.class')} ${pageProperty(name: 'page.sectionName')}">
```

That throws the same exception, but also works when using Grails 2.3.6.

Comment: I did some more debugging and found that RenderTagLib.getPage() is causing the issue. return (AbstractHTMLPage)getRequest().getAttribute(PAGE) is causing the issue because getAttribute(PAGE) results in an object of type Content2HTMLPage, which is not a subclass of AnstractHTMLPage, hence the classcastexception. Any ideas how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this same issue after upgrading from Grails 2.2.5 to 2.4.4. Changing/adding this line in Config.groovy solved it for me:

```
    grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true
```

Hope this helps someone - I was stumped for a couple days on this one.